# How do I print each result in each row separately?

Tags: python, list, format

I want it to print a table that shows each result in each row before adding them up.
Like this:

```
ID,Table Sales,Desk Sales,Chair Sales
413     23.0    52.0    532.0
5       32523.0 5323.0  5.0
325     25.0    3253.0  23.0
Total,32571.00,8628.00,560.00

Commission Table:
ID,Table Commission,Desk Commission,Chair Commission
413     2.30    7.80    26.60
5       3252.30 798.45  0.25
325     2.50    487.95  1.15
Total,3257.10,1294.20,28.00
```

But I keep getting this:

```
Sales Table
ID      Table   Desk    Chair
----------------------------------------
-1      412.0   421.0   421.0
Total,  412.00|421.00|421.00

Commission Table
ID      Table   Desk    Chair
----------------------------------------
-1      10.00   20.00   30.00
Total,  10.00|20.00|30.00
```

```
sale_list = []
commission_list = []

sale_person = int(input("Please input salesperson ID or -1 to end: "))

while sale_person != -1:
    table_sales = float(input("Enter table sales: "))
    while table_sales < 0:
        print("Invalid: Enter valid table sales")
        table_sales = float(input("Enter table sales: "))

    desk_sales = float(input("Enter desk sales: "))
    while desk_sales < 0:
        print("Invalid: Enter valid desk sales")
        desk_sales = float(input("Enter desk sales: "))

    chair_sales = float(input("Enter chair sales: "))
    while chair_sales < 0:
        print("Invalid: Enter valid chair sales")
        chair_sales = float(input("Enter chair sales: "))
    
    sale_person = int(input("Please input salesperson ID or -1 to end: "))


if table_sales <= 500:
    table_commission = 10
elif table_sales > 500 and table_sales < 1000:
    table_commission = 20
elif table_sales >= 1000 and table_sales < 1500:
    table_commission = 30
else:
    table_commission = 40

if desk_sales <= 500:
    desk_commission = 20
elif desk_sales > 500 and desk_sales < 1000:
    desk_commission = 30
elif desk_sales >= 1000 and desk_sales < 1500:
    desk_commission = 40
else:
    desk_commission = 50

if chair_sales <= 500:
    chair_commission = 30
elif chair_sales > 500 and chair_sales < 1000:
    chair_commission = 40
elif chair_sales >= 1000 and chair_sales < 1500:
    chair_commission = 50
else:
    chair_commission = 60

sale_info = f"{sale_person},{table_sales},{desk_sales},{chair_sales}"
commission_info = f"{sale_person},{table_commission},{desk_commission},{chair_commission}"

sale_list.append(sale_info)
commission_list.append(commission_info)

print("\nSales Table")
print("ID \tTable   Desk \tChair")
print("-"*40)
total_sale = [0, 0, 0]
for row in sale_list:
    sales = row.split(",")
    sale_person, table_sales, desk_sales, chair_sales = sales
    table_sales, desk_sales, chair_sales = float(table_sales), float(desk_sales), float(chair_sales)
    print(f"{sale_person}\t{table_sales}\t{desk_sales}\t{chair_sales}")
    total_sale[0] += float(table_sales)
    total_sale[1] += float(desk_sales)
    total_sale[2] += float(chair_sales)

print(f"Total,\t{total_sale[0]:.2f}|{total_sale[1]:.2f}|{total_sale[2]:.2f}")

print("\nCommission Table")
print("ID \tTable   Desk \tChair")
print("-"*40)
total_commission = [0, 0, 0]
for row in commission_list:
    commission = row.split(",")
    sale_person, table_commission, desk_commission, chair_commission = commission
    table_commission, desk_commission, chair_commission = float(table_commission), float(desk_commission), float(chair_commission)
    print(f"{sale_person}\t{table_commission:.2f}\t{desk_commission:.2f}\t{chair_commission:.2f}")
    total_commission[0] += float(table_commission)
    total_commission[1] += float(desk_commission)
    total_commission[2] += float(chair_commission)

print(f"Total,\t{total_commission[0]:.2f}|{total_commission[1]:.2f}|{total_commission[2]:.2f}")
```

I keep getting only the last input result of my sales, commission and saleperson ID.

```
Sales Table
ID      Table   Desk    Chair
----------------------------------------
-1      412.0   421.0   421.0
Total,  412.00|421.00|421.00

Commission Table
ID      Table   Desk    Chair
----------------------------------------
-1      10.00   20.00   30.00
Total,  10.00|20.00|30.00
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda big question, I'm going to break it down in smaller pieces to show the fix.

The following code is basically what your code wants to do (I describe all the functions after this)

```
def main():
    salepersons, sales, commissions = [], [], []

    saleperson = int(input("Please input salesperson ID or -1 to end: "))
    while saleperson > -1:
        table_sales, desk_sales, chair_sales = get_sales()
        table_commission, desk_commission, chair_commission = get_commissions(table_sales, desk_sales, chair_sales)

        salepersons.append(saleperson)
        sales.append((table_sales, desk_sales, chair_sales))
        commissions.append((table_commission, desk_commission, chair_commission))

        saleperson = int(input("Please input another salesperson ID or -1 to end: "))

    print_data(salepersons, sales, commissions)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But instead, you never appended the data to the lists when you asked the user for data, so whenever you input anything you just erase the previous input

> ```
> while sale_person != -1:
>     ...  # some code inside the loop
> ...  # some code outside the loop
> sale_list.append(sale_info)  # appending after the loop
> commission_list.append(commission_info)  # appending after the loop
> ```

This leads to only the last input being kept. Fixing this should be enough to solve your issue.

---

The following are the changes I made to the rest of the code. I'll give my reasoning wherever I can.

```
def get_sales():
    table_sales = get_sales_for_item("table")
    desk_sales = get_sales_for_item("desk")
    chair_sales = get_sales_for_item("chair")
    return table_sales, desk_sales, chair_sales
```

Since the code is almost the same I created a function that asks for sales and reduced the repetition code.

```
def get_sales_for_item(item):
    sales = int(input(f"Enter {item} sales: "))
    while sales < 0:
        print(f"Enter valid {item} sales")
        sales = int(input(f"Enter {item} sales: "))
    return sales
```

This just asks for the sales amount until it gets a valid number and returns said number to the calling function

```
def get_commissions(table_sales, desk_sales, chair_sales):
    table_commission = get_commissions_for_item("table", table_sales, commission_rules)
    desk_commission = get_commissions_for_item("desk", desk_sales, commission_rules)
    chairs_commission = get_commissions_for_item("chair", chair_sales, commission_rules)
    return table_commission, desk_commission, chairs_commission
```

Similarly, I have put the code to ask the user for the commission in a function. It will loop over the received rules and return the commission.

```
def get_commissions_for_item(item, sales, rules):
    for sale_range, commission in rules[item]:
        if sales <= sale_range:
            return commission
    # sales bigger than any rules, returning the last commission in the rules
    return commission
```

Here I loop over `rules` for the given `item` until I discover the commission accrued. If sales was bigger than all available rules I just return the last commission in the rules.

```
commission_rules = {
    "table": [(500, 10), (1000, 20), (1500, 30), (-1, 40)],
    "desk": [(500, 20), (1000, 30), (1500, 40), (-1, 50)],
    "chair": [(500, 30), (1000, 40), (1500, 50), (-1, 60)],
}
```

And here are the rules for your problem. The key for this dict is the item name, the value for this dict are the commission rules. e.g. [(500, 10), (-1, 20)] means the same as 'if sales was lower than or equal to 500 then commission is 10 else commission is 20'.
This facilitates adding new rules or changing them.

```
def print_data(salepersons, sales, commissions):
    if salepersons == []:
        return
    print("\nSales Table")
    print("\t".join(["ID", "Tables", "Desks", "Chairs"]))
    print("-" * 40)
    for sp, (tb_rev, dk_rev, ch_rev) in zip(salepersons, sales):
        print("\t".join(str(x) for x in [sp, tb_rev, dk_rev, ch_rev]))
    tables_total = sum([sale[0] for sale in sales])
    desks_total = sum([sale[1] for sale in sales])
    chairs_total = sum([sale[2] for sale in sales])
    print("\t".join(str(x) for x in ["TOTAL", tables_total, desks_total, chairs_total]))

    print("\nCommission Table")
    print("\t".join(["ID", "Tables", "Desks", "Chairs"]))
    print("-" * 40)
    for sp, (tb_com, dk_com, ch_com) in zip(salepersons, commissions):
        print("\t".join(str(x) for x in [sp, tb_com, dk_com, ch_com]))
    tables_total = sum([commi[0] for commi in commissions])
    desks_total = sum([commi[1] for commi in commissions])
    chairs_total = sum([commi[2] for commi in commissions])
    print("\t".join(str(x) for x in ["TOTAL", tables_total, desks_total, chairs_total]))
```

Here I'm receiving `salepersons`, `sales`, and `commissions` as tuples instead of strings so I can manipulate them better.
I zip `salepersons` with `sales` and then with `commissions` to get each line and then print them for each table.
To avoid repetition I switched the string containing the rows with a `"\t".join()` call.
I used list comprehension in `tables_total`, `desks_total`, and `chairs_total` so I could use the sum function to sum every item in sales and commission.